# vb.net Listview selectedItemChanged event fires when trying to select already selected item

Tags: vb.net, listview

Anyone has a clue what might go wrong? This behaviour happens after I make some changes in the grid that associates properties to the items in the listview, select a different item, at save prompt I cancel and revert the selection, now if I try to select the already selected item event fires. I dont know why.

I do change the selection programatically when I revert the selection if I cancel at the save promt.

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to ask. Perhaps other people can jump in and edit his question for more answer.

Comment: @RyanFung I`m asking if this behaviour was seen before. It is rather simple, SelectedItemChanged event fires when trying to select already selected item in the Listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reproduce this problem. It's resolved if you set the MultiSelect property to false. However, if you need multiple selections, another solution will be needed.

A UserControl 'wrapper' around the ListView that handles the SelectedItemChanged event and only responds if the item is different is an option.

Comment: I have the MultiSelect property set to false so the multiple selection part doesnt apply here. Any other ideas you might have?

Comment: Saying that, even when I programmatically select an already selected item (listView1.Items[2].Selected = true;) I don't get the event re-firing, regardless of MultiSelect property value.

Comment: I`ll let it fire and use some conditions to jump the part where I get promted to save because modifications were found. Thanks for your time.